# Enable Sequential kafka Asynchronous send() message for 2 kafka producers configured in 2 regions

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, synchronous

Scenario : Two kafka producer configured with different bootstrap servers (different regions),  we are trying to send message to primary cluster first and if primary cluster is down ( due to timeout or exception) , it switches to secondary cluster.
Can it be done via asynchronous call, i.e. to check primary cluster health and if unable to send message, switch to other cluster? Currently im doing in a sync way as its blocking call for web threads :

```
 for (int i=0; i <delegateList.size(); i++) {

            T delegate = delegateList.get(i);
            ClusterHealthCheck clusterHealth = this.clusterHealth.get(i);

            if( !clusterHealth.isHealthy()) {
                continue;
            }

            try {
// proxy is used which is on send() kafka producer api
                Object result = method.invoke(delegate, args);

                if( result instanceof Future) {
                    result.get();
                }

                return result;
```

Comment: Why are you using reflection when you already have an instance of the template?

Comment: "As it's blocking for web threads". Unclear what this means, but perhaps you should be using Spring webflux, instead, which is completely async

Comment: @OneCricketeer : i'm using Kafka clients Producer api in a non spring application, and whenever we hit producer.send() we delegate that request here to check health of cluster and send message sequentially

Comment: @OneCricketeer : blocking web threads  as when we hit submit for sending message to kafka its waits till delivery.timeout is over if one of the cluster is down

Comment: correct code as per non spring implementation

Comment: Have you tried using a Vertx Kafka client, which is also non blocking?

Comment: no i havent, will it be a non blocking call for both clusters if we try to do it

Comment: The same producer client would be used for both clusters, so yes? The only reason your code is currently blocking, anyway, is because you're requesting the Future result, which isn't necessary, and you can instead pass an async callback to the send function. You still don't need reflection

Comment: actually this code is from a library we created which is generic ( use case cache clusters , kafka clusters etc.) for non spring app, hence we just build a proxy object on client side and delegate health checks of cluster whenever method is invoked, we are using async call back to send method , but future.get() is root cause
Can we use isDone() and then check future.get() ? will it be async then ?

Comment: You never should need to check the future at all. You can modify Kafka `acks=1` or `acks=all` with at least `min.in.sync.replicas=2` , and `replication-factor=3` on the topic to ensure data is durably written... Why do you care if the producer actually returns a result?

Comment: either producer returns a result or we get a timeout exception or other exception ( if suppose that region is down), if later's the case we can then switch to our next configured producer ( from  delegateList in above code), that was initial design